# Authentication failed. Please check your username/password. [Server response: DNS Error: Domain name not found code(0) ]

Tags: email, dns, gmail

i am trying to configure my host mail to gmail. POP3 is working. But while trying to configure it shows following error. DNS working perfectly and i can able to receive mails via POP3 in gmail. Only i cannot able to reply from this same mail id, which is receiving.

PORTs are tried is : 587 and 465

both are not working. Please help me out

```
Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.[Server response: DNS Error: Domain name not found code(0) can]
```

what will i have to do?

Comment: Just an assumption: does an address of your SMPT the same as in MX record for your domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happen because the service was down at the time. Later , I have configured again in 587 port with **Secured connection using TLS (recommended)** method.